# Не получается решить задачу на программирование: калькулятор

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Пытаюсь решить [задачу](https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80-13262/step/5?unit=3447) условие, которой приведено ниже.
Проблема в том что на больших числах моя программа выдает какой-то совершенно адский результат. К примеру для числа 96234 программа выдает такую простыню чисел http://pastebin.com/8H5SvPKb (сравните с тем результатом, который приведен в условии). В принципе я понимаю почему так происходит, но другой идеи для решения данной задачи у меня нет. Подскажите как тут грамотно решить эту задачу.

#### Условие задачи:

> У вас есть примитивный калькулятор, 
>       который умеет выполнять всего три операции с текущим числом x: 
>       заменить x на 2x, 3x или x+1. 
>       По данному целому числу 1≤n≤10^5 определите минимальное число операций k, 
>       необходимое, чтобы получить n из 1. 
>       Выведите k и последовательность промежуточных чисел.

```
Sample Input 1:
1
Sample Output 1:
0
1 

Sample Input 2:
5
Sample Output 2:
3
1 2 4 5 

Sample Input 3:
96234
Sample Output 3:
14
1 3 9 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234
```

#### Мое решение:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    int i = 1;
    vector<int> m;
    m.push_back(i);
    while (i != n) {
        if (i * 3 <= n) {
            i *= 3;
        } else if (i * 2 <= n) {
            i *= 2;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
        m.push_back(i);
    }

    cout << m.size() - 1 << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size(); i++) cout << m[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: поменяйте ваше тип переменных из int на long, или double

Comment: @Saidolim А смысл, максимальное значение по условиям задачи 10^5, можно умножать на 3. Значит максимально возможное число 300 тыс. это как то меньше обычно 4х байтного int

Comment: А я что-то не уверен, что ответ, приведенный в примере с числом `96234` правильный. А как раз такое большой массив чисел и получается

Comment: @abg Проблема в том, что начало с умножения на 3 не является оптимальным для минимального кол-ва операций. И тут вопрос в том, а имеет ли право программа пользоваться какими либо другими операциями для поиска лучшего результата, при условии что результат разумеется будет состоять только из указанных операций

Comment: Алгоритм в примере понятен, он основан на вычислениях "от конца". Т.е. делим заданное число на 3. Если не делится без остатка, то на 2. Если опять не делится, то вычитаем 1 и все  повторяем, пока не получим 1. Остается доказать, что он оптимален.

Comment: @avp как же мы с вами ошибались в итоге))

Comment: На егэ 11 класс такая задача. Только там n уже дано, оно не превышает 100, нужно посчитать.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Напишу свое решение, которое, по-моему, намного проще понять, чем уже опубликованные (я, например, не понимаю, почему они правильные).

Алгоритм такой: заводим список, в котором в i-ой позиции будем хранить минимальное число шагов, известное на данный момент, за которое можно попасть в N. В начале нам будет известно только то, что в N-ой позиции стоит 0. Затем начинаем бежать по списку из конца в начало. На каждом шаге проверяем, из каких позиций мы можем попасть в текущую, и для этих позиций обновляем расстояние, если оно лучше, чем уже посчитанное ранее. К моменту когда мы прийдем в i-ый элемент, там будет записано минимальное расстояние, т.к. мы перебрали все варианты. Код такой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <climits>

int main() {
  int N;
  std::cin >> N;
  std::vector<int> steps(N + 1, INT_MAX);
  steps[N] = 0;
  std::vector<int> next_num(N + 1, -1);

  for (int i = N; i > 1; --i) {
    int s = steps[i] + 1;
    // 3 * x
    if (!(i % 3) && steps[i / 3] > s) {
      steps[i / 3] = s;
      next_num[i / 3] = i;
    }
    // 2 * x
    if (!(i % 2) && steps[i / 2] > s) {
      steps[i / 2] = s;
      next_num[i / 2] = i;
    }
    // x + 1
    if (steps[i - 1] > s) {
      steps[i - 1] = s;
      next_num[i - 1] = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << steps[1] << std::endl;
  for (int i = 1; i != -1; i = next_num[i])
    std::cout << i << ' ';
  std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Сложность алгоритма -- линейная.

Результаты на тестах:

http://ideone.com/cuHyDP

```
 stdin
1
￼ stdout
0
1
```

http://ideone.com/Ttku2H

```
 stdin
5
￼ stdout
3
1 3 4 5
```

http://ideone.com/G5yg1I

```
￼ stdin
96234
￼ stdout
14
1 3 9 10 11 33 99 297 891 2673 8019 16038 16039 48117 96234
```

Comment: Вы буквально опубликовали идею, которую я хотел испробовать с утра проснувшись)) Не успел.

Comment: Если пройтись по возрастанию номера и до упора - получится алгоритм Дейкстры. который у меня реализован с дополнительными опциями.

Comment: Непонятно, что имеется в виду под "линейной" сложностью алгоритма.

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, значит вычислительная сложность алгоритма принадлежит O(N). Грубо говоря, время работы линейно зависит от N.

Comment: @dzhioev Критиковать Вашу идею - значит, идти против собственных убеждений. На самом деле у Вас тот же алгоритм Дейкстры, но по убыванию. И он тоже гарантированно сойдётся. Резюме: он лучший для задачи в постановке ТС (+1) .

Comment: @YuriNegometyanov, ну да, именно он. Назад бежать удобней, т.к. не надо проверять, попадают ли (2 * i) или (3 * i) в диапазон -- (i /2) и (i / 3) всегда попадают.

Comment: Хотя с другой стороны, если бежать вперед, не надо проверять делится ли i на 2 или на 3.

Comment: Думаю, разницы нет.

Answer (score 9):

У меня получилась другая последовательность чисел, но количество операций 14:

```
    long num = 96234;
    long x = num;
    int k = 0;

    while(x > 1)
    {
        if (x % 3 == 0)
        {
            x = x / 3;
            k++;
        }
        else if (x % 2 == 0)
        {
            if ((x - 1) % 3 == 0 && x % 4 != 0)
            {
                x--;
                k++;
                continue;
            }
            x = x / 2;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            x--;
            k++;
        }
    }
```

Последовательность чисел:
1 2 6 7 21 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234

Comment: Я был бы за ваш вариант)).. правда для числа `82` код выдаст только `27
9
3
1` вроде бы

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - `81 27 9 3 1` vs `41 40 20 10 5 4 2 1`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Смотря что и откуда выводить. Или я не понимаю, в чем проблема. У меня выводится количество операций 5. Это разве неправильно?

Comment: @ElenaOblomova - Ваше решение правильное. В образце они так и поступают (см. `10 -> 9`, а не `10 -> 5`).

Comment: @ElenaOblomova Апнул ваше решение. Может я просто что-то не туда ввожу, что у меня   по вашему образцу не получается до конца корректно. Но думаю это оптимальнее логики, предложенной мной.

Comment: @Igor ну да, я из этого и исходила, меня смутило только то, что в примере получилась другая последовательность чисел.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Спасибо. Может, в выводе чисел отличия у Вас... Как будто последнее (или первое, смотря откуда смотреть) число не выводится...

Comment: @ElenaOblomova, ваше решение у меня не проходит через систему онлайн-проверки https://stepic.org/lesson/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%80-13262/step/5?unit=3447 Валится на каком-то тесте, говорит, что неправильно посчитал количество операций.

Comment: @abg, А не говорит, на каком тесте? Хоть какое-то описание есть?

Comment: @ElenaOblomova, нет, известно только то, что решение не проходит. И меня честно говоря смущает в Вашем решении строка "if ((x - 1) % 3 == 0)". Мне кажется это условие не всегда будет обеспечивать оптимальное решение.

Comment: @ElenaOblomova - Так. Давайте разбираться с числом `64`: Elena - `64 63 31 30 10 9 3 1`, Алексей - `64 32 16 8 4 2 1`.

Comment: или `16`: `16 15 5 4 2 1` vs `16 8 4 2 1`

Comment: @Igor, я поправила условие, по рассмотренным примерам работает правильно. Если на каком-то шаге получается уменьшить число на 1 и затем разделить на 3, это получается менее выгодно, чем дважды разделить на 2.

Comment: @ElenaOblomova - по-моему, Вы хотели проверить `x % 4 != 0`, a не `(x - 1) % 2 != 0`

Comment: Да, конечно, для x % 4 != 0

Comment: Хотя результаты для (x - 1) % 2 != 0 у меня получаются такие же. Пока не придумала, как обосновать

Comment: проверка условия `(x - 1) % 2 != 0` внутри условия `x % 2 == 0` - бессмысленна

Comment: Кстати, для 84 (x - 1) % 2 != 0 лучше, чем x % 4 == 0

Comment: лучше, чем `84 28 27 9 3 1`?

Comment: нет, для x % 4 != 0 у меня получается 84 28 14 7 6 2 1

Comment: @ElenaOblomova - ну вот, Вы нашли контрпример для последней версии Вашего кода.

Comment: Да, поэтому, прежде чем постить новый вариант, я перепроверю еще раз.

Comment: О! У Вас уже есть новый вариант?

Comment: у меня есть подход, который я пытаюсь применить.

Comment: Видимо мы оба опубликовали ответы немного поторопившись))

Answer (score 7):

Итерационный алгоритм. Название говорит само за себя, алгоритм пытается перебрать все возможные варианты. По этой причине может работать долго.
Для ускорения работы глубина рекурсии ограничена числом, выдаваемым алгоритмом [Елены Обломовой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/195850/elena-oblomova)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int *VAR[100];
int LENS[100];
int IM[100];
int MAX_ITER;

int probe(int i,int iter)
{
 iter++; if(iter>MAX_ITER) return 10000;
 int j[3];
 int ret[3]; int m;
 if(i<=1) return 0;
 ret[0]=ret[1]=ret[2]=10000;
 j[2]=i-1; ret[2]=probe(j[2],iter);
 if(i%2==0) {j[1]=i/2; ret[1]=probe(j[1],iter);}
 if(i%3==0) {j[0]=i/3; ret[0]=probe(j[0],iter);}
 if(ret[0]<ret[1]) m=0; else m=1;
 if(ret[2]<ret[m]) m=2;
 if(ret[m]>=10000) return ret[m]+1;
 if(m) ret[m]=probe(j[m],iter);
 IM[iter-1]=j[m];
 ret[m]++;
 return ret[m];
}

int ElenaOblomovaAlg(int num)
{
 int x=num;
 int k=0;
 while(x > 1)
  {
   if (x % 3 == 0)  { x=x/3; k++; }
   else if (x % 2 == 0)
    {
     if((x-1)%3==0 && x%4 != 0) { x--; k++; continue; }
     x=x/2; k++;
    }
   else { x--; k++; }
  }
 return k;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int n,i;
    int o,j=0;
    memset(VAR,0,sizeof(int *)*100);
    memset(LENS,0,sizeof(int)*100);
    cin >> n;
    MAX_ITER=ElenaOblomovaAlg(n)+1;
    cout << "ElenaOblomova algorithm return " << MAX_ITER-1 << "\n";
    i=probe(n,0);
    if(i>1000) { i=MAX_ITER; cout << "Error recursion alg !!!\n"; }
    cout << "\ncount=" << i << "\n";
    i--;
    for (; i>=0; i--) cout << IM[i] << " ";
    cout << n;
    return 0;
}
```

Дает всегда оптимальное разложение, но его самого есть куда оптимизировать. Например разложение числа 99997 полным перебором требует порядка 1.6 миллиарда тестов.

Comment: Падает при введении 64 на выводе 10005-го элемента... Результат 10006...

Comment: Прикольно. мои тесты сбоев не давали, сейчас гляну как это с 64 так :)

Comment: @ElenaOblomova Понял, это последняя правка прямо тут подпортила. Поправил, в main к числу возвращаемому Вашим алгоритмом надо добавить 1, иначе он может не найти решения. И там еще одну проверку чуть позже сделаю

Comment: @Mike - а ответ какой для 99997?

Comment: 19 операций: 1 3 9 18 19 38 76 77 231 693 694 2082 2083 4166 8332 8333 24999 49998 99996 99997

Answer (score 4):

По вашему алгоритму так и будет.. все правильно получается...Большая портянка чисел. Но на самом деле алгоритм другой должен быть:

В обратную сторону - берем исходное число. Делим на 3. Если есть остаток - не учитываем, а вместо этого делим на 2, если остаток опять будет от деления, значит вычитаем 1..... повторяем. пока не дойдем до 1.

Comment: Одновременно с моим комментом (+1).

Comment: @avp Да. я в начале коммент писать начал, а потом решил, уж пусть будет ответом.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, то решение, которое я привел оно плохое. Вопрос тут в том, а нет ли здесь более лучшей идеи для решения? Может быть как-нибудь через динамическое программирование или еще что-то в этом духе? Попробую Ваше решение разобрать.

Comment: И правильно (даже если этот способ и не всегда оптимален. Но интуитивно он представляется оптимальным).

Comment: Я также пошел от этого предположения. Но у меня получился результат, отличный от примера:
`1 2 4 5 10 11 22 66 198 594 1782 5346 16038 16039 32078 96234` - 
15 шагов, а не 14. То есть не все так просто

Comment: Да, тут небольшой подводный камень есть. Надо обмозговать его

Comment: Возможно  как раз в интервале с 1 по 10 нужно действовать именно по алгоритму автора. А при числах выше - комбинировать.

Comment: Похоже, для четных чисел вариант (-1, :3), если делится, должен иметь приоритет над :2.

Comment: Алгоритм выдаёт неоптимальный результат. Возьмём число 82. Получается 1 2 4 5 10 20 40 41 82, - 9 чисел, в то время как оптимально 7: 1 2 3 9 27 81 82

Comment: Уточню: для четных чисел, не делящихся на 3.

Comment: @Igor тогда получится что как только число делится без остатка на 2, будет происходить декремент. что повысит количество операций

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - Нет, только если после декремента оно делится на 3.

Comment: @abg Предлагаю вам взглянуть на решение, предложенное `Elena Oblomova` . Оно более оптимальное.

Comment: Оптимальность обоих методов обосновать трудновато.

Answer (score 4):

Правильное направление - это динамическое программирование и алгоритм Дейкстры.
Надо просто завести массив на 10<sup>5</sup> элементов и по порядку, начиная с единицы, заполнить его минимально возможным количеством операций калькулятора (массив $steps). Наличие операции инкремента в калькуляторе даёт гарантию, что это возможно.

Кроме того, для каждого из чисел запоминаются также предыдущие числа (от одного до трёх), соответствующие одному шагу оптимального решения (массив $previous). Это позволяет полностью избавиться от перебора (с момента заполнения массивов сложность алгоритма равна количеству операций калькулятора).
В итоге удаётся:

1. Определить минимальное количество операций калькулятора по пути к каждому числу.
2. Найти число, требующее больше всего операций (77759 - 24 операции).
3. Двигаясь по нулевым элементам массива previous, моментально получить один из оптимальных путей.
4. Рекурсивным обходом массива previous максимально быстро определить все оптимальные способы, которыми можно получить данное число (на примере числа 96234).

Программа (на PHP):

```
function pre($i, $chain){
    global $previous;
    if($i==0){
        print("<br>");
        foreach($chain as $val) print(" $val"); 
        return;
    }
    array_push($chain, $i);
    $cnt = count($previous[$i]);
    if(!$i) return;
    for($c=0; $c < $cnt; $c++){
        pre($previous[$i][$c], $chain);
    }
}

$n = 96234;
$lim = 100000;
$steps = array();
$steps[1] = 0;
$previous[1]=array(0);
$max = 0;
for($i=2; $i<=$lim; $i++){
    $i1=$i-1;
    $steps[$i] = $steps[$i1]+1;
    $previous[$i] = array($i1);
    $i2 = $i>>1;
    if(2*$i2 == $i){
        if ($steps[$i2] < $steps[$i]-1){
            $steps[$i] = $steps[$i2]+1;
            $previous[$i] = array($i2);
        }elseif($steps[$i2] == $steps[$i]-1){
            array_push($previous[$i], $i2);
        }
    }
    $i3 = (int)($i/3);
    if(3*$i3 == $i) {
        if ($steps[$i3] < $steps[$i]-1){
            $steps[$i] = $steps[$i3]+1;
            $previous[$i] = array($i3);
        }elseif($steps[$i3] == $steps[$i]-1){
            array_push($previous[$i], $i3);
        }
    }
    if($steps[$i]>$max) $max = $steps[$i];
}

asort($steps);  
var_dump(array_slice($steps, 99990, 99999, true));

printf("<br> steps[%d] = %d: &emsp; ", $pr=77759, $steps[$pr]);
while($pr>1) printf(" %d", $pr=$previous[$pr][0]);
print("<br>");

printf("<br> steps[%d] = %d: &emsp; ", $pr=99977, $steps[$pr]);
while($pr>1) printf(" %d", $pr=$previous[$pr][0]);
print("<br>");

printf("<br> steps[%d] = %d: &emsp; ", $pr=96234, $steps[$pr]);
while($pr>1) printf(" %d", $pr=$previous[$pr][0]);
print("<br>");

$chain = array();
pre($n, $chain);
```

Результаты:

```
array (size=10)
  86399 => int 22
  51407 => int 22
  69119 => int 22
  60911 => int 22
  93311 => int 23
  77758 => int 23
  77757 => int 23
  77755 => int 23
  51839 => int 23
  77759 => int 24

steps[77759] = 24:   77758 38879 38878 19439 19438 9719 9718 4859 4858 2429 2428 1214 607 606 303 101 100 99 33 11 10 9 3 1

steps[99977] = 19:   99976 49988 24994 24993 8331 2777 2776 1388 694 693 231 77 76 38 19 18 9 3 1

steps[96234] = 14:   48117 16039 16038 8019 2673 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1

96234 48117 16039 16038 8019 2673 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 2673 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 3 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 2 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 2 1
96234 48117 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 8019 2673 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 2673 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 891 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 297 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 99 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 33 11 10 9 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 3 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 2 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 21 7 6 2 1
96234 32078 16039 16038 5346 1782 594 198 66 22 11 10 9 3 1
```

Суммарное время выполнения ~ 1 секунды.

Comment: а зачем нам вычислять вот это все, если нужно решить задачу, скажем, для 64? Неэффективно получается... Хотя, конечно, зависит от применения

Comment: Интересно посмотреть график steps[x]

Comment: @Elena Oblomova Потому что алгоритмы с полным перебором могут непредсказуемо "захлебнуться" на длинном пути (77759), а эвристические алгоритмы - остановиться на неправильном решении. Т.е. не гарантируют результат для _любого_ числа в указанном диапазоне. И чем нам плохо время 1 с?

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov, время может быть хорошо или плохо в зависимости от сценария или требования. Если пользователю дается возможность ввести число и через 1 с выдается ответ, то он подождет, ничего не случится. А если это часть работы нагруженной системы, скажем, обрабатывающей запросы большого числа пользователей, быстродействие может оказаться недостаточным.

Comment: @Elena Oblomova Т.е. с вопросом "почему так лучше" мы разобрались. А остальное - мелкие детали. Но если речь идёт про одно число (64) и ооочень нагруженную систему, можно установить $lim=64.

Comment: @Yuri Negometyanov, Ваш алгоритм имеет место быть, просто им пользоваться нужно осторожно.

Comment: @sercxjo Непонятно, как это грамотно сделать. Но я готов вывести на печать любой срез.

Comment: @Elena Oblomova Согласен с Вами - к блоку питания лучше не прикасаться =)